# Design a process map

Tags: spreadsheet

I would like to have something like this>
[image]

My data looks like this>

[image]

But with more than 400 rows or interactions. So, first, I would need to add all my interactions, like this

[image]

How can I count those interactions automatically?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sq2veRAXjNn6Y1NphB7phaOUeghqQgvPJ9VNgBghf_Q/edit#gid=0

Thanks,

Comment: I think you'll need more detailed information than what you've indicated. As an example, look at the section **How Excel columns interact with Visio flowchart components** on [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-visualizer-diagram-17211b46-d144-4ca2-9ea7-b0f48f0ae0a6#howexcelvisio) to get a better idea of how specific you'll have to be in assigning the direction of the arrows, labels (the "counts" in your data), and other information.